# Where did the execute call go in BigQuery Requests?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am following the Code lab here https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava to make requests to big query. One of the code samples here says:

```
Datasets.List datasetRequest = bigquery.datasets().list(projectId);
DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
```

But I am getting a "The method execute() is undefined for the type Bigquery.Datasets.List" error.

Any idea whats going on?
I am on version google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev42-1.12.0-beta if that matters.

Comment: Try to use rev47. We work with BigQuery API libraries from rev3. And we have an issue with API access several times we did not update the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add this dependency to get it working. The dependency in the pom for google-api-services-bigquery seem to be wrong. Which causes this exception.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```